# How to determine the natural direction of text

Tags: swift, cocoa, text

`NSTextField` and `NSParagraphStyle` have a `alignment: NSTextAlignment` property that allows to align text to the left, center, right, or natural, which means that text in a left-to-right app UI is aligned left and text in a right-to-left app UI is aligned right. What I'm looking for is how to align text in the opposite direction of the natural direction, but independently of the app UI language, as the app can contain text in different languages. (Note that using the `leading` and `trailing` `NSLayoutConstraint`s is not enough as they only align the text bounding box, but not the text within the bounding box.)

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or is there a built-in function that allows to determine what the natural direction of a `String` is, so that I can then calculate the alignment by flipping that value?

Comment: A string doesn't have a natural direction. Is `userInterfaceLayoutDirection` what you're looking for?

Comment: How would you use `userInterfaceLayoutDirection` to accomplish this? It cannot change the text alignment.

Comment: I would use `userInterfaceLayoutDirection` to determine what the natural direction is.

Comment: Isn't that to determine the natural direction of the app or UI language? I'm specifically looking for a way to determine the direction (or opposite direction) of any given text, independently of the user language.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to flip the natural direction of a `NSTextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've updated the question to make it clearer.